# Flutter - Convert Hexadecimal to Decimal signed 2's compliment

Tags: dart, hex, decimal

I'm trying to convert the hex value to decimal and I was able to convert it using `int.parse('8E', radix: 16)`, but I'm not able to get the decimal from signed 2's complement.
If you convert 8E(hex):
What I'm getting from this `int.parse('8E', radix: 16)` is 142.
What I want is -114

please use this converter for reference - https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html

Can somone help me to get the decimal from signed 2's complement?

Comment: The solution provided by both julemand101 and Irn works perfectly. Is it possible to mark both solutions as answers? Once again, thank you both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `int.parse` returns a 64-bit signed integer and your hex value represent a signed 8-bit value.

By doing a "bit" of bit-shifting, we can convert the value so the numeric value are the same as the 8-bit value represented:

```dart
void main() {
  int value = (int.parse('8E', radix: 16) << 56) >> 56;
  print(value); // -114
}
```

Comment: This also works as expected. Awesome. Thanks @julemand101

Answer (score 3):

The result is 142, because Dart integers are not 8-bit.

If you want to convert it to the numerical value of an 8-bit two's complement number with the same (low) eight bits, you can do:

```dart
int parseInt8(String source) {
  var hexValue = int.parse(source, radix: 16);
  return hexValue.toSigned(8);
}
```

The `toSigned` method, with argument `8`, truncates to the low 8 bits, and then sign-extends those back to the full integer size.

If you want that value as decimal, you can do `toString()` on it.

Comment: Awesome. This works as expected. Thanks @Irn